# How to handle dynamic routes at the same level for Static and SSR pages using Next.js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, slug, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm facing the next situation, I'm using Next.js and I need to manage two different files that will use dynamic routes. The reason is that the site has static and SSR pages, the static ones use `getStaticPath` and `getStaticProps` functions and the SSR use `getServerSideProps`. So Next doesn't allow to have those functions on the same file and that's why I can't have just one file that renders different page components or some logic to manage ssr or static.

Expected:

`mysite.com/[...slug]` will be for static page

`mysite.com/[...category]` will be for ssr page

All pages come from a wordpress CMS and their url structure cannot be changed. I mean the ssr url page from mini example above can't be `mysite.com/etc/[...category]`

Comment: That's not possible with Next.js built-in routing. Next.js uses a [file-system based routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction), if both dynamic routes are on the same level it wouldn't know what path to match. You'll have to use a different folder structure.

Comment: I had the same situation and ended up using conditional rendering. `if url param is category => render ssr page, else render static page`